# Integrate two projects in app Xcode

Tags: xcode

I had two Xcode projects ,i want to combine these two projects how can i do this ,is there anyway to do this

I'm new to this concept i don't know how to handle this concept ,can you direct me with your suggestions

I have copied my project B as a subproject of main project.On UIButton click i want to use the classes in project b ,how can i call project b classes there

Comment: It depends on what you mean by combine? You can place both projects in a workspace file. That won't create conflicts between them

Comment: Add the code from one project into the other one! You have not included any details at all about the projects, what type of projects? do they use story board? do they share classes? Have you read the developer docs or searched for your answers?

Comment: I have copied my project B as a subproject of main project.On UIButton click i want to use the classes in project b ,how can i call project b classes there

Comment: @Lirik i have added two projects two single workspace ,both two projects are mostly of similar class names ,while importing class(.h file) in main project  from projectB i'm getting error

Comment: Are you trying to import a class from projectA to some other class in projectB? you can't do that. Placing 2 projects in a workspace doesn't mean you can access one project from another.  please explain what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Lirik i'm having 2  projects in main project when i click one uibutton have to access other project from there wat to do for that

Comment: Ok, now its a bit more clear.. you actually CAN add another project to the navigator of your project A. ( and no need for a workspace). The only thing you need to make sure of is that there  are no duplicate names in both of your projects. if so, change the names.

Comment: ok i renamed all the files but now in my main project how can i call subproject

Comment: @Lirik If i'm importing subproject .h files in main project getting error